# NewtonSoft Json retrieve data with brackets method

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Currently I am using the YouTube API to get some data. The data is in json and I am trying to get a single part of it.

The problem that I am facing right now is that I want to use the following method:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();

string jsonData = client.DownloadString("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=" + videoId + "&part=contentDetails&key=");

var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonData);

string duration = results["items"]["contentDetails"]["duration"];
```

Currently this results in an error:

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

The problem I am facing right now is that I don't know how to deserialize the object properly so I can use text indexes to get to the data. I used to do it like this before but I can't recall it and can't find anything about my method.

Comment: Doesn't it `Deserialize` the object? What else happens?

Comment: I get an error on the following line: string duration = results["items"]["contentDetails"]["duration"]; saying the following: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

Comment: You get that error because you deserialized to type `object` instead of some other type. Do you *have* to access via the brackets method? Why not deserialize to some strongly typed object, ex: `MyCustomType instance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyCustomType>(jsonData);`

Comment: @mason when you don't have a custom type defined to parse JSON string, you use `var` to have it, and access data using `.`

Comment: @Shaharyar No, `var` is not magical. You would still have to specify to the deserializer what type you wish it to be. Perhaps you're thinking of the `dynamic` keyword, which should not be abused.

Comment: @mason Exactly `dynamic` thanks

Answer (score 8):

What you should do is define a class with all your properties that matches your JSON, and then pass that class as a type argument to the deserialization:

```
Results results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Results>(jsonData);
```

I don't have more info about your JSON, but a quick definition would look like this:

```
public class Results
{
     public Items items { get; set; }
}

public class Items
{
     public ContentDetails contentDetails { get; set; }
}

public class ContentDetails
{
    public string duration { get; set; }
}
```

If you need help converting a JSON response to C# classes, you can use converters such as http://json2csharp.com/

---

You can also deserialize to a dynamic type, like so:

```
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonData);
```

Then, you just access your properties:

```
string duration = results.items.contentDetails.duration;
```

However, using `dynamic` is **not recommended** most of the time, because it effectively removes static typing, so you must be sure that `duration` will be a string, or it will throw a runtime exception when you try to access it.

Answer (score 2):

Normally if I'm dealing with a JSON payload that I don't feel like mapping to a strong type I use JObjects which allow for LINQ to JSON.

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
```

This will allow the properties of the object to be indexed using `[]` syntax.

More information on using LINQ to JSON in the [API docs](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Get your `Deserialized` data into `dynamic` type:

```
dynamic results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonData);
```

and then access it using `.`:

```
string duration = results.items.contentDetails.duration;
```

The syntax you're using is used in javascript.

Comment: `results` is of type `object` and has no `items` property.

Comment: No, it does not. `object` has no `items` property. If you didn't know that, here's [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I tried it but I get the following warning:  'object' does not contain a definition for 'items' and no extension method 'items' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You're missing the `dynamic` keyword.

Comment: What do you mean with dynamic?

Comment: @Quartermain use `dynamic` instead of `var`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
dynamic results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonData);
```

then you can do

```
string duration = results["items"]["contentDetails"]["duration"];
```

or

```
string duration = results.items.contentDetails.duration;
```

Reference to *dynamic* keyword on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx